# MVC3 Razor - Editing a variable length list

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I followed Steven Sanderson's blog - http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

When I try to add another row of items, rather than adding the row it sends me to the url with the returned partial view.

How do I prevent this from happening and hence add an actual row?

## My code below along with the path (as I am using Areas):

### MyWebUI

#### Areas/Client/MyMoveItems/Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MovinMyStuff.Domain.Entities.MoveItem>
@using MovinMyStuff.WebUI.HtmlHelpers

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h1>My Move Items</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table class="move-item">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Item
        </th>
        <th class="dimension-header">
            L
        </th>
        <th class="dimension-header">
            W
        </th>
        <th class="dimension-header">
            H
        </th>
        <th class="weight-header">
            Wt
        </th>
        <th class="qty-header">
            Qty
        </th>
        <th>
            Addt'l Work
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <div id="editorRows">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("_MoveItemEditorRow", item);
                }
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
@Html.ActionLink("Add Item", "Add", new { area = "Client" }, new { id = "addItem" })
<input type="submit" value="Finished" />
}
```

#### Areas/Client/MyMoveItems/_MoveItemEditorRow.cshtml

```
@model MovinMyStuff.Domain.Entities.MoveItem
@using MovinMyStuff.WebUI.HtmlHelpers

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("moveitems"))
{
    <div class="editorRow">
<tr>
    <td class="item-name">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MoveItemType)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MoveItemType)
</td>
<td class="item-dimension">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Length)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Length)
</td>
<td class="item-dimension">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Width)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Width)
</td>
<td class="item-dimension">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Height)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Height)
</td>
<td class="item-weight">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Weight)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight)
</td>
<td class="item-qty">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)
</td>
<td class="work-items-group">
    <table class="work-items">
        <tr>
            <td>Assembly</td>
            <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Assemble)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Assemble)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="work-items">
        <tr>
            <td>Glass</td>
            <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HasGlass)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HasGlass)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</div>
}
```

#### Areas/Client/Controllers/MyMoveItemsControllers.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MovinMyStuff.Domain.Entities;
using MovinMyStuff.Domain.Concrete;

namespace MovinMyStuff.WebUI.Areas.Client.Controllers
{ 
public class MyMoveItemsController : Controller
    {
    private EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();

    //
    // GET: /Client/MyMoveItems/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var moveitems = db.MoveItems.Include(m => m.Move);
        return View(moveitems);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<MoveItem> moveitems)
    {
        return View("Completed", moveitems);
    }

    public PartialViewResult Add()
    {
        return PartialView("_MoveItemEditorRow", new MoveItem());
    }
}
}
```

#### HtmlHelpers/HtmlPrefixScopeExtension.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MovinMyStuff.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
public static class HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions
{
    private const string idsToReuseKey = "__htmlPrefixScopeExtensions_IdsToReuse_";

    public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem(this HtmlHelper html, string collectionName)
    {
        var idsToReuse = GetIdsToReuse(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, collectionName);
        string itemIndex = idsToReuse.Count > 0 ? idsToReuse.Dequeue() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // autocomplete="off" is needed to work around a very annoying Chrome behaviour whereby it reuses old values after the user clicks "Back", which causes the xyz.index and xyz[...] values to get out of sync.
        html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}.index\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"{1}\" />", collectionName, html.Encode(itemIndex)));

        return BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html, string.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex));
    }

    public static IDisposable BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldPrefix)
    {
        return new HtmlFieldPrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix);
    }

    private static Queue<string> GetIdsToReuse(HttpContextBase httpContext, string collectionName)
    {
        // We need to use the same sequence of IDs following a server-side validation failure,  
        // otherwise the framework won't render the validation error messages next to each item.
        string key = idsToReuseKey + collectionName;
        var queue = (Queue<string>)httpContext.Items[key];
        if (queue == null) {
            httpContext.Items[key] = queue = new Queue<string>();
            var previouslyUsedIds = httpContext.Request[collectionName + ".index"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previouslyUsedIds))
                foreach (string previouslyUsedId in previouslyUsedIds.Split(','))
                    queue.Enqueue(previouslyUsedId);
        }
        return queue;
    }

    private class HtmlFieldPrefixScope : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TemplateInfo templateInfo;
        private readonly string previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

        public HtmlFieldPrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            this.templateInfo = templateInfo;

            previousHtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
            templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = previousHtmlFieldPrefix;
        }
    }
}
}
```

#### Scripts/mms-custom.js

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: this.href,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
});
return false;
});

$("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
$(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
return false;
});
```

#### Views/Shared/_ClientLayout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/mms-custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
    .DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css")
                                .Add("telerik.default.css"))
)
</head>
<body>
    <section>
    @RenderBody()
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very few of us will read that big hunk of code without your guiding us as to what parts are relevant.  Please try to paraphrase your question some, explaining which specific lines of code you are having trouble with.

Comment: @KirkWoll - I guess those in the category of "Very few" decided to read this. Thanks for the thoughts. ( :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**First:** Make sure your jQuery code (`Scripts/mms-custom.js`) is inside `$(document.ready` -- it does not look like it is if that is if you posted your entire file above.

If that doesn't fix it by itself, try this:

**Second:**

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) { $("#editorRows").append(data);  return false;}
    });
    return false;
});
```

in place of your code:

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: this.href,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
});
return
```

I had a similar problem when using that blog post as a point of reference.

Comment: Actually I JUST figured it out! Can you believe it was because I had the script in the head tag and it REALLY NEEDS to be before the closing body tag. That was a real B I T _ H man. Cost me hours of time.

Comment: @HelloJonnyOh That's why you should always put them in a `$document.ready` function because it forces the .js to not start working until the entire document is ready - when the contained instructions will make sense.  Something like that ^^.  I'm glad it works.

Comment: @HelloJonnyOh Also, consider marking a correct answer, if you desire.